# Switchable connection strings via code at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a WPF application. It has many blocks that access the database. The connection string is determined by a setting in my *App.config* file.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyEntities())
{
    // ...
}
```

But now I need the ability to switch between different databases at run time. I've updated the code to manage a list of databases, along with a connection string to each one.

My question is, is there any way to have the existing code using the connection string indicated by my code without having to change the existing code? For example, perhaps I can create a static connection string property in my entities class, and then modify that class to use the property each time it connects to the database.

Has anyone done this? Any tips to do this in a painless way?

Comment: By switch you mean just once at startup or during the lifetime of application?

Comment: @Evk: By *run time*, I mean while the application is running. It could happen any number of times during an instance of the application.

Comment: And all instances of context using the same connection string?

Comment: @Evk: Yes. Once the switch is made, all access to the database will use the new connection string.

Comment: @JohnH: But the existing code wouldn't function right. It would continue to use the connection string in my configuration file. Moreover, if I updated each block to now provide a connection string to the constructor, if I miss just one my application would drive into the ditch.

Comment: Well, then I'd indeed just use static `ConnectionString` property in such case, which you use from default context constructor (`public MyContext():base(ConnectionString) {}`). Above comment was probably for @JohnH.

Comment: @Evk: Sorry, I'm on my phone and didn't realize two people had responded. Yeah, that seems like the easiest approach to me.

Comment: @JohnH: That's an interesting way to deal with the exception I raised. But I'd still prefer if I can control this from a single location.

Comment: @Evk: Write that up as an answer if you like.

Comment: I would use a factory for that

Comment: @SirRufo: Well, feel free to write an answer if you want. To be honest, I can't see anything from that brief comment that would indicate why that might be better.

Comment: Well an abstract definition of the factory (interface) and use it instead of new MyEntities(). According to the concrete implementation of the factory you can handle anything you like

Comment: @JonathanWood: As you are using WPF and DBContext can live for long time don't forget there is ChangeTracker and it holds Local version of entities. Asking for entity with Id that already exists locally can lead to security issues exposing data from different database. I would rather dispose existing DbContext and create new one passing connection string into constructor instead of changing connection string property.

Comment: @cloudikka: I'm not sure I understand the concern. If you look at my code snippet, the DBContext is destroyed immediately at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: @JonathanWood Yeah, sorry. I read to the end and forgot about the code sample. Stupid mistake. Don't worry then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best idea I came up with was to add a static `ConnectionString` property to my entities class. And then modify the constructor to pass this property to the base class.

One issue is that any change to the entities class would be overwritten by the T4 scripts when the model is updated. You could create a partial class and define your own constructor, but if that constructor has no arguments then it will conflict with the existing constructor.

My solution for this was to actually edit the existing T4 script directly, as shown below.

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    // Original code
    //public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
    //    : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    //{

    // Modified code
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base(ConnectionString)
    {

    // End of modified code

<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}
```

When you save the T4 script, it will immediately regenerate the code.

Comment: How does the T4 script practically change the connection string at runtime? Is it being generated by some other process or service?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson: The default constructor passes a string that indicates the connection string should be read from the config file. My change causes it to pass the static `ConnectionString` property. The entire point of my question was that I wanted to be able to change this connection string from code, and now I can by setting the value of that property. Then, when I create an instance of the DbContext, it will use that value.

Comment: Oh, I see - that was existing code which you modified to suit your need.